# Add already installed Image Color Profiles (.icm) into an image in C#

Tags: c#, image, colors

In one of my C# project (.net framework 4.0), I need to add the installed color profiles in windows, into images if it already have no color profiles in it. 
I Google and found nothing in .net for the color profile management, So I adopt the imagemagick library and use its "addprofile" method but after adding and saving the image whenever i ready the image it doesn't contain the color profile. While searching on the internet I found to apply colorprofile.sRGB before applying your custom color profile and I do the same and when I read the image it contain the color profile "icc" in the image. Following is color profile adding code

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(outputFilePath))
            {
                ImageMagick.ColorProfile colorProfile = image.GetColorProfile();
                if (colorProfile == null)
                {
                    //Add sRGB color profile before adding your custom color profile
                    image.AddProfile(ImageMagick.ColorProfile.SRGB);
                    //ICSPrfile is the object containing the name and path of availabe prfiles
                    //_profilesRGB is the list containing the ICSProfiles
                    foreach (ICSProfile prof in _profilesRGB)
                        if (prof.Name.Equals(comboBoxRGBProfile.SelectedItem))
                            image.AddProfile(new ImageMagick.ImageProfile(prof.Name, File.ReadAllBytes(prof.FilePath)));

                    //Write update profile file
                    image.Write(outputFilePath);
                }//End if
            }//End using
```

Now, I am not sure, after writing this code whether my image contain the custom color profile or not.Did I wrote a correct code? and how can I check the color profiles in an image.

Comment: What is the type of your output image?

Comment: It should be the same as input image

Comment: Not all formats support color profiles. What are the formats you are working with?

Comment: Well, I am intended for applying color profile to those images which support it. For testing purposes I am using jpg and png

Comment: Would you mind starting a topic here also: https://magick.codeplex.com/discussions? It is a bit easier to communicate there.